# regex with python / re.match doesn't work

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I've got stringText like that

```
sText ="""<firstName name="hello morning" id="2342"/>
<mainDescription description="cooking food blog 5 years"/>
<special description="G10X, U16X, U17X, G26X, C32X, G34X, G37X, U39X, C40X, G46X,C49X, U54X, U55X, A58X"/> 
"""
```

I'd like receive:

> cooking food blog 5 years

I tried many different regex

like:

```
p = re.compile('<mainDescription description=\"([^\"]+)\"\/>')
print re.match(p, sText)
```

or

```
p = re.compile(ur'<mainDescription description="([^"]+)"\/>')
```

and using (.+) 
according [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) my regex should work correctly, but it doesn't. 
I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use findall():

```
print re.findall('<mainDescription description=\"([^\"]+)\"\/>', sText)
```

Output:

```
['cooking food blog 5 years']
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search_12.py", line 10, in <module>
    print re.search(p, sText).group(0)
  File "C:\Miniconda2\lib\re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: sorry, i copy-paste bad one -> Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Just try use only findall

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's because you're using [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) instead of [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). `re.match()` Searches from the start of the string while `re.search()` searches anywhere. This works:

```
sText ="""<firstName name="hello morning" id="2342"/>
<mainDescription description="cooking food blog 5 years"/>
<special description="G10X, U16X, U17X, G26X, C32X, G34X, G37X, U39X, C40X, G46X,C49X, U54X, U55X, A58X"/> 
"""
p = re.compile('<mainDescription description=\"([^\"]+)\"\/>')
print re.search(p, sText).group(1)
```

By the way, you do not need to escape the quotation marks (`"`) if you're using `'` meaning this is enough:

```
re.search('<mainDescription description="([^"]+)"/>', sText)
```

Comment: @PyLearn Not entirely sure why it's not working for you but if you'll copy-paste my code it should work :-/

Answer (score 0):

`re.match` returns a `match` object, from which you need to retrieve the desired group.

```
sText ="""<firstName name="hello morning" id="2342"/>
<mainDescription description="cooking food blog 5 years"/>
<special description="G10X, U16X, U17X, G26X, C32X, G34X, G37X, U39X, C40X, G46X,C49X, U54X, U55X, A58X"/> 
"""
r = re.compile("""<mainDescription description="(?P<description>[^"]+)"\/>""")
m = r.match(sText)
print m.group('description')
```

Note that it's also possible to access the group using the index (0 in this case) but I prefer to specify a keyword.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'